# Is the bean for the class @Configuration always null?

Tags: java, spring

Assume that all files are in a package named tom.

A.java

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class A {
    public int x;
}
```

Teztt.java

```
@Configuration
public class Teztt {
    @Bean
    public A getA() {
        return new A(56);
    }
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Tezt.java

```
public class Tezt {
    @Autowired
    public Teztt teztt;
}
```

Tezt.xml

```
<bean class="tom.Teztt" />
<bean id="idTezt" class="tom.Tezt" />
```

Runner.java

```
public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("tom/Tezt.xml");
        Tezt t = (Tezt) context.getBean("idTezt");
        if(t.teztt == null) {
            System.out.println("NPE");
        }
    }
}
```

The output of above is NPE. My question is I want to get Object of Teztt having non-null value. Is there a way in Spring to do this thing or will it always be null. Please help.

Comment: When using XML you have to tell Spring to use annotations for processing add `<context:annotation-config />` to your xml configuration (and of course the appropriate namespace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since class Tezt do not initialize its member "public Teztt teztt", there's no reason to have a not null teztt. Either initialize teztt element inside Textsz class, or add a method, such as init() and modify spring beans configuration in runtime environment. For example:

```
public class Tezt {
    @Autowired
    public Teztt teztt = new Teztt();
}
```

but this way it never stops.

Using init-method inside xml bean:

```
 public class Tezt {
     public void init() {
         this.teztt = new Tezt();
     }
 ...
```

and

```
<bean id="idTezt" class="tom.Tezt" init-method="init" />
```

but this stops after the second.

Comment: @Autowired
    public Teztt teztt = new Teztt(); Really?

Answer (score 1):

Edited: in your xml you need to insert:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

and you need to declare your bean:

```
@Configuration
public class Config{
    @Bean
    public Teztt getTeztt(){
      return new Teztt();
    }

    @Bean
    public A getA() {
        return new A(56);
    }
}
```

Comment: context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("tom/Tezt.xml"); Registres all the beans. Why do it explicitly.

Comment: Wait, you are autowiring configuration class, that is wrong

Comment: I need to use the functions inside AuthConfiguration.

Comment: This is only the configuration of your classes. You need to write your class:
`public class Teztt {
  public void doThis(){
  }
}`